# Force variable pass as object

Tags: php, oop, object

I need to define the type of passed variable as an generic object, how?

Tried:

```
public function set($service = null, (object) $instance) {
    [..]
}
```

Can `stdClass` help? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, in php all classes aren't derive from the common ancestor.

So doubtfully you can use current php's implementation to state "object of any class"

Comment: So, solution only inside the function with `is_object`?

Comment: @Gabriel Santos: yes. Or, if you could, just create interface and `implement` it in each required class

Comment: No, interface in this case is so ugly. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

No, the object has to be some class. You can give the any class name as object's type

```
public function set($service = null, ClassName $instance) {
    //now the instance HAS to be the object of the class
}
```

Or a basic trick would be to create a basic class yourself

```
Class GenericObject {}
$myobj = new GenericObject();
$myobj -> myCustomVar = 'my custom var';

//Now send it
public function set($service = null, GenericObject $instance) {
   [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for samples, but, it is for a Service Locator, which will not work correctly with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel,

if what you want to do is check if the variable is an object, you could do this:

```
public function set($service = null, $instance) {
    if (!is_object($instance)) return null; //or whatever
    [..]
}
```

What are you trying to prevent with that? With your declaration, you would get an exception if the variable is not an object (it will not cast it).

Comment: I have a "exception catcher".

Comment: I know about `is_object` inside `set` function, but I thought about casts.

Comment: @Gabriel Santos: to be precise it has nothing to do with "casts" in php, it is called "type hinting"

Comment: `function set($service = null, (object) $instance)` casting `$instance` as Object